# Automatically add rows in google sheets when importing data from other sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from several sheets into one, But they need to come between data in other cells.

So i have:

**Fixed text data 1**

`=FILTER('Car Parks'!A:AC, NOT(ISBLANK('Car Parks'!A:A)))`

`=FILTER('Chapter 8'!A:AC, NOT(ISBLANK('Chapter 8'!A:A)))`

`=FILTER('Production'!A:AC, NOT(ISBLANK('Production'!A:A)))`

`=FILTER('CSAS'!A:AC, NOT(ISBLANK('CSAS'!A:A)))`

**Fixed text data 2**

However, each of the FILTER functions will return a #REF as it cannot overwrite the other FILTER functions or the fixed text data.

Each filter function works correctly as long as there is not too many rows required.

Is there a straight forward way to allow each of these FILTER functions to add rows until they are completed, before the next filter function or fixed text data?

**Context:**

- Used to generate a quote document.
- Each Filter function imports shift timings for different sectors on a job
- Fixed text data 1 is the initial data such as client details
- Fixed test data 2 in the terms and conditions of the quote

Answer (score 1):

you could append the filters and fixed text 2 to keep it dynamic. try:

`={IFNA(FILTER({'Car Parks'!A:AC;'Chapter 8'!A:AC;Production!A:AC;CSAS!A:AC},{'Car Parks'!A:A;'Chapter 8'!A:A;Production!A:A;CSAS!A:A}<>""));"TERMS AND CONDITIONS";"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Rem laudantium reiciendis eos error quia aut autem molestiae aut temporibus magnam!"}`

Comment: Thanks! Had to take out the text bit for the formula to run, but the rest does what i need it to largely. T&Cs can be included as a separate document so i can work around that. Is there a way to get it to keep the original format (It currently converts times back to numbers)?

Comment: you can maybe just set the `Formatting` of these specific columns to Time in the formula output sheet.